# PHP - Where should Unit Of Work lie in an MVC application?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, domain-driven-design, unit-of-work

## Background Info for Question

In my index.php file I have this:

```php
$service_factory = new ServiceFactory(new MapperFactory($db), new DomainFactory);
```

My understanding of how a UnitOfWork should work with my application is this (state is referring to dirty, clean, etc.):

- Mapper - marks an object's state

  - Either `$user->markNew();` or `$uow->registerNew($user);`
- Domain - can check it's current state. Ex: `$this->isDirty();`
- Service - where `commit()` is called to complete the transactions

  - Either `$this->uow->commit()` or `$mapper->commit()`

My commit function of my UnitOfWork looks like this (feel free to improve):

```php
public function commit()
{
    // Inserts the new objects
    foreach ($this->newObjects as $newObject) {
        $mapper = $this->mapperFactory->createFromDomainObject($newObject);
        $mapper->insert($newObject);
    }

    // Update the dirty objects
    foreach ($this->dirtyObjects as $updateObject) {
        $mapper = $this->mapperFactory->createFromDomainObject($updateObject);
        $mapper->update($updateObject);
    }

    // Delete the removed
    foreach ($this->deletedObjects as $deletedObject) {
        $mapper = $this->mapperFactory->createFromDomainObject($deletedObject);
        $mapper->delete($deletedObject);
    }
}
```

## Option #1 - ServiceFactory

**Pro**: If I have one service calling another, I won't have to worry about not passing Domain objects between each other, since they will share the same instance of the UnitOfWork.

**Con**: I would have to pass the UnitOfWork object all the way down to the mapper object, which would be this many levels: ServiceFactory -> Service -> MapperFactory -> Mapper... Ew. That doesn't sit well with me.
Also, since the UnitOfWork requires a MapperFactory, my index.php would change to this:

```php
$uow = new UnitOfWork(new MapperFactory($db));
$mapper_factory = new MapperFactory($db, $uow);
$service_factory = new ServiceFactory($mapper_factory, new DomainFactory, $uow);
```

As you can see, the it's like a bundle of UnitOfWorks and MapperFactories everywhere, just not pretty.

## Option #2 - Service

**Pro**: I wouldn't have an ugly index.php file. I would just create a new instance of UnitOfWork for each Service object. Inside my ServiceFactory would look like this:

```php
/**
 * Create method
 *
 * This will create a new Service class if it hasn't 
 * already been instantiated, and return it.
 *
 * @param string $name          The class name
 * @return mixed
 */
public function create($name)
{
    $class = '\\MyApp\\Service\\' . $name;
    if ( array_key_exists($class, $this->cache) === false) {
        if (class_exists($class)) {
            $uow = new UnitOfWork($this->mapperFactory);
            $this->cache[$class] = new $class(
                $this->mapperFactory, 
                $this->domainFactory,
                $uow
            );
        } else {
            throw new Exception(sprintf('Service class %s does not exist.', $class));
        }
    }
    return $this->cache[$class];
}
```

This seems a lot cleaner to me.

**Con**: I would not be able to have services call each other. However, I am in the beginning stages of this project, and this is my first attempt at a somewhat "correct" MVC application, so I'm not sure if I will have Services calling each other a lot or not at all.

## Option #3 - MapperFactory

**Pro**: Not really any that I can see, but it's still an option. In my index.php I could have this:

```php
$uow = new UnitOfWork($db);
$service_factory = new ServiceFactory(new MapperFactory($db,$uow), new DomainFactory);
```

My UnitOfWork class could extend the MapperFactory class, and therefore not needing to create two instances of MapperFactory. I would pass the same instance of the UnitOfWork to each Mapper.

**Con**: I would have to commit the transactions in my Service class by doing something like this:

```php
$this->mapperFactory->unitOfWork->commit();
```

Too many function calls for my liking. Also, I'm not sure how I would allow the Domain Objects to check their state without a reference to the UnitOfWork Object.

### Maybe there's something I'm missing, but any suggestions or helpful insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit of Work control would typically be placed in the Application Service in DDD, so I guess that means option #2.

Note though that your whole question might be due to an overcomplicated design.

- Too many `Factories` is generally a code smell -- especially the `DomainFactory` one :) Is there a specific reason to use them ?
- Creating an (Object/relational, I guess) mapper instance by passing it a domain object seems contrived. Also, it's not obvious what a `MapperFactory` is about. Does it create mappers ? Does it *map and create* ?
- Are you trying to implement your own Unit of Work from scratch ? Might be reinventing the wheel, most ORM frameworks have that functionality built in. I don't know about PHP though.

Comment: "Note though that your whole question might be due to an overcomplicated design." I had a feeling that was the case, but wasn't sure how/where. I see your point about too many factories. Is it best to just create them manually when needed? The mapper factory creates Data Mappers (Ex in Service: `$this->mapperFactory->create('User');`) creates a new `MyApp\Mapper\UserMapper` instance. I have copied code from some other UOW's I found online that seem to work well. Just had trouble implementing them into my app.

Comment: I only ever use Factories (in the `Abstract Factory` pattern sense) when an object needs to be in control of the entire lifecycle of one of its dependencies, creating it and disposing it as it sees fit. Which means, almost never. 99% of the time I inject the dependency directly through the constructor of the object rather than injecting *a Factory that will produce the dependency*. You might want to apply the same reasoning to strip your system from all superfluous Factories.